# Linux / FVWM / Acroread -- don't autoraise

Tags: fvwm, acrobat-reader

I'm not sure where my problem lies.

I'm running Slackware Linux, Xorg 7.5, FVWM 2.6.1, Acrobat Reader 9.5.3

Every time my mouse goes into the Acroread window, the Acroread window auto-raises.  I don't want it to do that.  When I put another window on top of the Acroread window, I want it to stay visible and on top.

I have

```
Acroread*AutoRaise: false
```

in my `.Xdefaults` file, but that does not seem to do it.

How can I make Acroread not auto-raise on focus?

=====

Edit: I have a longtime .fvwm2rc file that prevents windows from auto-raising.  This line is commented out:

```
#AutoRaise 750
```

The only other references to `Raise` are inside functions, and I'm not using those.  Acroread is the only window (that I'm aware of off the top of my head) that auto-raises on focus.

Comment: Do you have anything related in fvwmrc? I used that file to configure focus behavior

Comment: Nothing related.   "AutoRaise" line is commented out.  No other window does this.  Only acroread.